# Can these multiple if statements be condensed?

Tags: python

I made a simple program that tells the user what cards are still in a deck based on the cards seen.If one looks at the code you can see that there are several if statements that do almost the same thing. Could anyone help me condense these?

```py
for card in cards_seen:
    if card.endswith('C') == True:
        Deck["clubs"].remove(card)
    if card.endswith('D') == True:
        Deck["diamonds"].remove(card)
    if card.endswith('H') == True:
        Deck["hearts"].remove(card)
    if card.endswith('S') == True:
        Deck["spades"].remove(card)
```

Comment: It seems like `card` instances should have a `suit` property. Then you could just use something like `Deck[card.suit].remove(card)`.

Comment: This is too broad and opinion based for here since there's likely many different ways to approach this. Note though that the `== True` part is unnecessary since `if` is already checking if its truthy, and all the conditions could be "connected" by using `or`: `if card.endswith('C') || card.endswith('H')... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Step 1: remove the redundant comparison with `True`:

```
if card.endswith('C'):
    Deck["clubs"].remove(card)
if card.endswith('D'):
    Deck["diamonds"].remove(card)
if card.endswith('H'):
    Deck["hearts"].remove(card)
if card.endswith('S'):
    Deck["spades"].remove(card)
```

Step 2: only 1 `remove` method call

```
for card in cards_seen:
    deck = None
    if card.endswith('C'):
        deck = Deck["clubs"]
    if card.endswith('D'):
        deck = Deck["diamonds"]
    if card.endswith('H'):
        deck = Deck["hearts"]
    if card.endswith('S'):
        deck = Deck["spades"]
    deck.remove(card)
```

Step 3: use a dictionary for the deck mapping

```
card_to_deck = { 'C':"clubs", 'D': "diamonds", 'H':"hearts", 'S':"spades"}
for card in cards_seen:
    deckname = card_to_deck[card[-1]]
    Deck[deckname].remove(card)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a dictionary to simplify the code quite a bit:

```py
card_suits = {
    'C': 'clubs',
    'D': 'diamonds',
    'H': 'hearts',
    'S': 'spades'
}
for card in cards_seen:
    suit = card_suits[card[-1]]
    Deck[suit].remove(card)
```

Some remarks:

1. Read about boolean expressions. You dont need to include `== True`.
2. Read about slices. You can use `text[-1]` to get the last character, but having said that, `.endswith` is a more versatile method.

Comment: you probably need to test if key is in dict to avoid key errors

Comment: Depends on how and where the cards are generated. If you're creating the cards, it's unnecessary, if user supplies the input, sanitization is required.

Answer (score 0):

To begin, you can remove the useless `== true` instructions.

You may create a dictionary like this:

```
card_map = { 'C': "clubs", 'D': "diamonds", 'H': "hearts", 'S': "spades" }
```

And then you can simplify your source code like this:

```
for card in cards_seen:
    deck_to_update = [value for key, value in card_map.items() if card.endswith(key)][0]
    Deck[deck_to_update].remove(card)
```

Explanations:

- to begin, you extract the name of the deck to update, with the same instruction you have before
- then you update the deck, removing the seen card